# Firebase firestore query not working in React Application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a basic React project to learn firestore with the data as follows:

a BookEntries collection comprised of documents like this ->

Author: "AuthorName" (String)
Title: "BookTitle" (String)
YearRead: 2022 (number)

I want to be able to query my documents by the YearRead, I have defined a function to do this in a separate file:

```js
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export const getBookEntriesByYear = async(year) => {

    const q = query(collection(db, "BookEntries"), where("YearEntered", "==", year));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
    })

}
```

When I run my React app, and use this function in App.js, nothing gets logged to the console. I am confused because I have another function where I get all documents from the collection that works that looks like this:

```js
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export const getAllBookEntries = async() => {

    const bookEntries = [];

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "BookEntries"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        bookEntries.push(doc.data());
    });
    return bookEntries;
}
```

Here is the code in App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getAllBookEntries } from "./firebase/getAllBookEntries";
import { getBookEntriesByYear } from "./firebase/getBookEntriesByYear";

const App = () => {
  const [bookEntries, setBookEntries] = useState([]); // this will store all of our BookEntry data from firebase
  const [bookEntriesByYear, setBookEntriesByYear] = useState([]); // this will initially just be a copy of our bookEntries array but will update when year stateful value changes in real impl.

  useEffect(() => {
    // initially will just grab all of our bookEntries
    getAllBookEntries().then((data) => {
      setBookEntries(data);
      setBookEntriesByYear(data); // initially is just a copy of our bookEntries array 
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // check to see if getBookEntriesByYear function works
    const year = 2022;
    getBookEntriesByYear(year);
  }, []);

//   console.log(bookEntries);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Someone please help :) The getAllBookEntries function when logged, successfully logs my data from my database to the console.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything seems fine and should work. Are you sure your query returns something at all ie `querySnapshot.size > 0` ?

Comment: Hello, yes my firestore database is super simple currently with only 3 entries, this is just a practice project before I build the real one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like I have answered my own question. I changed YearEntered to YearRead and it worked as expected :)